# Add NaN row to dataframe by group without changing Booleans and integers

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a dataframe with several aircraft plots:

```
0   3   AAL45   1649174961  16:09:21    40.31139    -74.62056   60  272.0   True    True    False   False   False
1   3   UAL245  1649174962  16:09:22    40.31194    -74.61889   60  272.0   True    True    False   False   False
2   3   DAL303  1649174963  16:09:23    40.31250    -74.61750   60  272.0   True    True    False   False   False
```

that I want to add a NaN row to, after each group, grouping by the aircraft callsign. I can add the rows, but something (numpy? changes the Booleans and integers to floats -

```
0   3.0 AAL45   1649174961  16:09:21    40.31139    -74.62056   60  272.0   1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   3.0 UAL245  1649174962  16:09:22    40.31194    -74.61889   60  272.0   1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   3.0 DAL303  1649174963  16:09:23    40.31250    -74.61750   60  272.0   1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

This is the code I used-

```py
df_nan = df.groupby('callsign').apply(lambda d: d.append({'callsign': d.name}, ignore_index=True)
```

How do I prevent that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. By building a function that adds a row of `None` values instead of `NaN`, the data types are preserved.
Curiously, the float values columns end up as NaNs, but OK. Here's my code -

```
def group_nan(group_id, input_df):
    # Function adds a nan row after each group in dataframe.
    # Requires group to sort by (eg 'callsign') and dataframe id.
    null_row = pandas.DataFrame({col:[None] for col in input_df.columns})
    grouped = input_df.groupby(group_id)
    plot_df = pandas.DataFrame()
    for _, group in grouped:
        plot_df = plot_df.append(group)
        plot_df = plot_df.append(null_row)
    return plot_df
```